# Quantity in checkout shopping cart doesn't work properly for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, addtocart

On live server the cart is working correctly. I change the quantity of a product in the cart then I push the "Update cart" button and all works fine. I transferred the site another domain and the cart quantity doesn't work anymore. As I change the quantity of a product and click the button the quantity remains the same. If I go back and try to add the same product to the cart, even if I specify a different quantity like 10 and not 1, in the cart only 1 item is added every time I click on "add to the cart" button and not 10 as specified. I cannot figure out where's the problem. I excluded my custom theme and rolled back to the default theme and the problem persist. this site other functionality work fine.

Comment: do you have any javascript errors?

Comment: no javascript errors show

Answer (score 1):

The below things you could do to make it work:

1. Clear all caches from **System->Cache Management** & try in Private window.
2. If you are using any **third party module** for related with cart update Add to cart etc. Disable that.
3. Check your log files in the directory **var/log** & see if any known error is there.
4. At last go to your **cart controller** & check the add & update action in there.

Comment: I will check 1-3 step but same problem. Please explain step 4

Comment: As the issue is quantity doesn't update so it's action defined in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php You just debug the addAction & updatePostAction inside that as quantity come to the controller or not etc. Remember just debug & not change the core code.

Answer (score 1):

In your Theme

```
/app/design/frontend/yourthemepackage/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml file
```

Or

```
/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/checkout/cart.phtml file
```

place on line after getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post"> paste the below code

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First clear the entire cache.
2. Login to admin panel
3. check the number of allowed items in cart option in admin.

At

```
adminpanel-->system-->configuration-->catalog-->Inventory-->Product Stock Options-->Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart.
```

I hope it will help to you.